# Synonyms for "labeling" of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology, root-systems

In Preprint 1 we write  numerical labels  0 or 1 at each vertex of a Dynkin diagram $D$. We call it a *labeling* of the graph (Dynkin diagram) $D$.

In Preprint 2 we consider an extended (affine) Dynkin diagram $\tilde{D}$. At each vertex of $\tilde{D}$ we write numerical labels 0, 1, or 2 such that a certain integer linear combination of the labels equals 2. We call it a *Kac 2-labeling* of $\tilde{D}$.

Now I am going to write Preprint 3, where I would like to use both *labelings* and *Kac 2-labelings*. I would like to use a better term than "Kac 2-labelings" in order not to confuse the reader.

**Question.** What synonyms to "Kac 2-labelings" of a graph (affine Dynkin diagram) can I use? Maybe "Kac 2-markings"?  Anything else?

Comment: How about "1-labellings" and "2-labellings" instead of "labellings" and "Kac 2-labellings" respectively?

Comment: @BorisBukh: No, this does not work. Actually I have Kac $n$-labelings (they classify inner automorphisms of order $n$ of complex simple Lie algebras), and a labeling is *not* a Kac 1-labeling.

Comment: How about "marking" and "labeling" ? Or "01-coloring"?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Thank you! I already have colorings as well, but "labeling" and "marking" will be good!